# Style Validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if it's possible to convert the following css to javascript? so basically it should implement the style rules after the onchange.

```
.appnitro input:required:valid, .appnitro textarea:required:valid {/* when a field is considered valid by the browser */
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
border-color: #28921f;
}


.appnitro input:focus:invalid, .appnitro textarea:focus:invalid { /* when a field is considere invalid by the browser */
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5d45252;
border-color: #b03535;
}


<script>
function myFunction(){
??????
}
</script>


<form id="form_664184" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="element_3"  name="element_2_1" value="Title" onchange="myFunction()" required />
</form>
```

Comment: Take a look at the DOM interface for [_CSSStyleSheet_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet), obtained from property _sheet_ of a _HTMLStyleElement_ `<style>`, or an item of `document.styleSheets`.

Comment: use this http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Here is how it should be:

```
yourElement.style.borderColor =  "#5cd053";
yourElement.style.boxShadow = "#5cd053";
```

Get the element by ID, class name or whatever else.

Comment: yes but that doesn't make sense because input:focus:valid and input:focus:invalid aren't being used, it will simply set the border and shadow to a default colour.

Comment: you are getting very near but I need to find out how I can get the invalid/valid bit working.